# Como generar un número de matricula de coche aleatoriamente en c++?

Tags: c++

Necesito generar 1 matrícula de un coche.
Una matrícula tiene la forma
LLDDDDLL siendo D un dígito [0..9] y L una letra mayúscula del
alfabeto latino, exceptuando vocales, Ñ y Q.

He hecho este código:

```
void generarmatricula (string &matricula){
    char nmatricula[8];
    string numeros="0123456789";
    string letrasma="BCFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ";
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) //generamos las 2 letras
    {
        nmatricula[i]=letrasma[rand()
        %letrasma.length()];
    }
    for(int i=2;i<6;i++) //generamos los 4 numeros
    {
        nmatricula[i]=numeros[rand()
        %numeros.length()];
    }
    for(int i=6;i<8;i++) //generamos las 2 letras
    {
        nmatricula[i]=letrasma[rand()
        %letrasma.length()];
    }
    nmatricula[8] = '\0';
    matricula = string(nmatricula); //lo pasamos a string para que sea mas facil su manejo
}

void mayuscula (string &s){
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){ //solo pasamos a mayuscula los caracteres
        s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Pero cuando genero la matricula me sale siempre la misma. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: cual es la funcion rand() que estas usando?? suena raro que no le pases parametros y la dividas por la longitud del vector...

Comment: Tu código funciona **perfecto**. ¿ Estás usando `srand( )` para establecer una semilla ?

Answer (score 4):

> Pero cuando genero la matricula me sale siempre la misma. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

Los números aleatorios... bueno, realmente son pseudoaleatorios (como puedes comprobar) se generan a partir de una semilla.

Es decir, se coge un número y al mismo se le aplica una función de la que se obtiene otro número diferente... este nuevo número es el que te devuelve la función `rand()` y es también la semilla del siguiente número aleatorio que se genere.

Lo que sucede en tu caso es que, al no generar una semilla diferente cada vez, la secuencia de números que genera `rand()` es siempre la misma.

Como te ha comentado @Trauma en los comentarios, tienes que usar `srand()` para establecer una semilla diferente al inicio del programa...

¿Y cómo se consigue una semilla diferente cada vez? Bueno, el truco más recurrido suele ser recurrir a la marca de tiempo:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

De esta forma, la semilla será la fecha actual del sistema expresada en segundos. Claro está esta llamada tienes que hacerla una sola vez... antes de empezar a generar números aleatorios:

```
char nmatricula[8];
string numeros="0123456789";
string letrasma="BCFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ";

srand(time(NULL)); // <<--- Inicializamos la semilla

for(int i=0;i<2;i++) //generamos las 2 letras
{
    nmatricula[i]=letrasma[rand()
    %letrasma.length()];
}
```

Pero claro, estamos en C++, no en C. En C++ hay formas mucho más elegantes de generar números aleatorios. En C++ tenemos la librería `random`, que incluye unas cuantas utilidades para generar números pseudoaleatorios según nuestras necesidades.

Lo primero es utilizar un generador aleatorio... eso lo podemos conseguir con:

```
std::random_device rd;
```

El problema que tiene `random_device` es que es bastante lento... es por ello que normalmente se tiende a utilizar únicamente como generador de la semilla inicial... para generar los números aleatorios se puede usar un generador más rápido, como  `mt19937`:

```
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
```

Y ahora el último paso, tenemos que elegir cómo queremos distribuir nuestros números aleatorios... éstos pueden ser enteros, reales, con una distribución uniforme, campana de gaus... en este caso buscamos una distribución uniforme de números enteros:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<char> dist_numeros(0, 9);
```

`uniform_int_distribution` es una plantilla que nos pide el tipo de dato que se va a generar. Como nosotros queremos generar caracteres a incluir en una plantilla, usamos el tipo `char`.

Con `dist1` podremos generar números en el rango [0, 9]. Ahora nos falta otra distribución para las letras:

```
string letrasma="BCFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ";
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist_letras(0, letrasma.length());
```

Nota que en este caso, `uniform_int_distribution` está especializada a `int`. Esto es porque esta distribución debe generarnos índices que aplicaremos a `letrasma`... y los índices es preferible, por legibilidad, que sean enteros.

Y ya tenemos toda la infraestructura configurada... solo nos resta generar números aleatorios:

```
for( int i=0; i<2; i++ )
{
  matricula += (letrasma[dist_letras(mt)]);
}

for( int i=0; i<4; i++ )
{
  matricula += (dist_numeros(mt) + '0');
}

for( int i=0; i<2; i++ )
{
  matricula += (letrasma[dist_letras(mt)]);
}
```

Claro que, en el caso de los números, podríamos pedir a la distribución que nos generase directamente caracteres entre el `'0'` y el `'9'`:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<char> dist_numeros('0', '9');
```

Con lo que ahora no tendríamos que transformar el valor obtenido:

```
for( int i=0; i<4; i++ )
{
  matricula += dist_numeros(mt);
}
```